# ¿Esta correcta la query?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo una pequeña duda y no se si esta correcta la query que he realizado. Estoy haciendo un proyecto con springbook y JPA.
La idea es que la query me devuelva el medico que su especialidad es de cabecera y que su paciente sea el nº de la SS que le pase por parámetros.
Esta es la estructura de las tablas

[image: tablas]

En la interfaz tengo la siguiente query.

```
@Repository
public interface PacienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Paciente, Integer> {

   @Query(value = "Select m from paciente p,medico m, medico_paciente mp "
            + "where p.nss= :nSSP and m.especialidad= 'cabecera' and p.nss= mp.nss and m.n_licencia = mp.n_licencia",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public Medico buscarMmedico(@Param("nSSP") int nSSP);

}
```

Uso native query por comodidad debido a las claves compuestas no se exactamente como hacerla con hibérnate.
No se si esta correcta o le faltaría algo.

Comment: no anduvo? da resultados erroneos? cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: aun no puedo probarla porque estoy perfilando el servicio pero la idea es si esta correcta o no no se si me olvide algo

Comment: Prueba tu query en la base de daota y fijate que devuelve lo que queres. Estas pidiendo que a ojo (igual que vos) miremos si el query funciona. No es mas facil probarlo?

Comment: Estás haciendo una query relacionando 3 tablas sin hacer JOINs, por lo que es normal que no te vaya.

Comment: es una query ademas en lenguaje sql con lo cual para que quiero el json